# How to color contour labels by a colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, contour, contourf

I have a contour plot that I color using the Yellow-Green color map named `YlGn` 
The labels at the darker fields do not appear well, as they are black.

Is there a method to color the labels in the inverse of the used colormap? i.e., to color the 0.39 label in white, and the 0.15 label in dark green, and the labels in-between accordingly.

[image]

I used `CS3 = plt.contourf(X, Z, M, levels, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn, extend='both')` for the filled contour and `CS4 = plt.contour(CS3, colors=('k',), linewidths=(1,))` for the line contour, and finally `plt.clabel(CS4, linewidths=2, fmt='%2.2f', colors='k', fontsize=14)` for the labels.

However when I tried to add `cmap=plt.cm.YlGn_r`  and removed the `colors='k'` to the labels (to reverse the colors) it did nothing.

**Note:** The codes used here are partially taken from [this documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-demo-py), but with some modifications to fit my data.

***Here are some data to try at a Jupyter notebook:***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(1.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn_r)
CS2 = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, color='k')
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=10,color='k')
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
```

Comment: You would get an answer much sooner (or even at all) by providing a [mcve] of the issue. I.e. some code one can copy&paste from the question, apply the necessary changes and write an answer. If I now have to create such example myself, I may end up, not answering at all because it's too tedious to replicate your case.

Comment: Ok I will post a sample code now

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, I added sample code to apply easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mixed up the arguments to `contour` and `contourf`. Applying the reverse colormap to contour works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab 

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(1.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
plt.figure()

CS2 = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn_r)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn)
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=10)

plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.show()
```

[image]

To use the same colormap for the lines as for the fills, but then use a different colormap for the labels, you need to define the colors manually. But the use of the existing levels helps you do that quite efficiently.

```
CS2 = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn_r)
CS = plt.contour(CS2, cmap=plt.cm.YlGn_r)
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=10, colors=plt.cm.Reds(CS.norm(CS.levels)))
```

[image]

Comment: Additional question if possible:  Here the labels are the same colors as the lines. What if I want the labels to follow different colormap?

Comment: Additionally, If we want special colors, we can define a colors tuple `cols = ('w', 'w', 'y', 'y','r', 'r','b', 'g','k', 'k')[::-1]` Then add it to `plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=10, colors=cols)` .